# disable selected input boxes when each dropdown option is selected?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm doing a form in html. When I select an option in the dropdown box, i want to have some input boxes enabled and some disabled based on the option selected. I can get one of the options done, but then when i change the duplicated code it messes up the first option.

```
javascript function:|
-------------------
<script>
function changeTextBox() {
var comp = document.getElementById('comparator');
if(comp.value=='billing_report')
    document.getElementById('from').disabled=false;
    document.getElementById('to').disabled=false;
    document.getElementById('component').disabled=true;
    document.getElementById('company').disabled=false;
    document.getElementById('salesperson').disabled=false;

else
 document.getElementById('job_no').disabled=true;
 document.getElementById('staff_name').disabled=true;
}
</script>
```

..

```
html code:|
-----------
<form name="Web Order Form" id="Web Order Form">
<table style="position:absolute; left:580px; top:210px; height:34px;" border="0"   bordercolor="#FFFFFF" style="background-color:#FFFFFF" width="50%" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">
  <tr style="position:absolute; left:0px; top:-42px;">
    <td>Select Report:</td>
    <label style="font-size:16px" for="comparator">Comparator:</label>
    <td><select id="comparator" name="comparator" onChange="changeTextBox();">
     <option value="please_select" id="please_select">Please Select...</option>
     <option value="billing_report" id="billing_report">Billing Report</option>
     <option value="courier_report" id="courier_report">Courier Report</option>
     <option value="management_summary_report" id="management_summary_report">Management Summary Report</option>
     <option value="production_report" id="production_report">Production Report</option>
     <option value="prospect_list" id="prospect_list">Prospect List</option>
     <option value="staff_absence_report" id="staff_absence_report">Staff Absence Report</option>
     <option value="stock_report" id="stock_report">Stock Report</option>
    </select>
    <label style="font-size:16px" for="to">Value:</label>
    <input type="number" id="value" disabled/></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
 <div style="position:absolute; left:545px; top:130px; width:510px; height:420px;  border:1px solid black">
  <tr>
   <td>From:</td>
   <td><input type="input" value="from" id="from"></td>
   <td>To:</td>
   <td><input type="input" value="to" id="to"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
   <td>Component:</td>
   <td><input type="input" value="" id="component"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
   <td>Company:</td>
   <td><input type="input" value="" id="company"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>

   <td>Job No:</td>
   <td><input type="input" value="" id="job_no"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
   <td>Sales Person:</td>
   <td><input type="input" value="" id="salesperson"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
   <td>Staff Name:</td>
   <td><input type="input" value="" id="staff_name"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr style="position:absolute; left:125px; top:275px;">
    <td><input type="submit" value="Build Report"></td>
    <td><input type="reset" value="Reset"></td>
  </tr>
 </div>

<div style="position:absolute; top:115px; left:730px; width:117px; height:30px; background-image: url(Images/reports.jpg); layer-background-image:url(Images/reports.jpg)">
</div>
```

so when billing report is selected for example then, 'Component', 'Job_No' and 'Staff_Name' will be disabled.

if component report is selected in the dropdown: then only 'To' and'From' will be enabled.

if production report is selected in the drop down then every input box is disabled.

and so on for the rest.I'm sure i can do the rest if i get the first two. Thanks. any help would be appreciated. I have looked at other question like this on stackoverflow, but just can't get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to reset the fields every time. Just add a function to reset all the fields, and using your conditions, just enable those fields that you want.

JS :

```
function changeTextBox() {
    var comp = document.getElementById('comparator');
    resetFields();    // Disabling all the fields.
    if (comp.value == 'billing_report') {
        document.getElementById('from').disabled = false;
        document.getElementById('to').disabled = false;
        document.getElementById('company').disabled = false;
        document.getElementById('salesperson').disabled = false;
    } else if (comp.value == 'courier_report') {
        // Enable the fields you want   
    } else {
        // Rest of your conditions.
    }
}

function resetFields() {
    document.getElementById('from').disabled = true;
    document.getElementById('to').disabled = true;
    document.getElementById('component').disabled = true;
    document.getElementById('company').disabled = true;
    document.getElementById('job_no').disabled = true;
    document.getElementById('salesperson').disabled = true;
    document.getElementById('staff_name').disabled = true;
}
```

Check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/niks999/vAzP9/1/)

Answer (score 0):

things have the nasty tendency to grow to really mess the code and make it unmanageable. I use a matrix to cope with the complexity

```
var disabler= [];
var disablerfields=      ['from','to','company','salesperson','component','job_no','staff_name'];
disabler['billing_report']=[1,     1,   0,        0,            1,          0,       0];
disabler['courier_report']=[0,     0,   1,        1,            1,          1,       1];
...
```

and the code (simplified)

```
var todo = disabler[document.getElementById('comparator').value];
for (var i=0, l=todo.length; i<l; i++) {
  document.getElementById(disablerfields[i]).disabled = todo[i];
```